# Trying to understand why function is returning undefined in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am having trouble understanding whats happening in this recursive function.
Why does y === undefined??

```
function f(num){
  if(num !== 10){
    f(num + 1);
  } else {
    return num;
  }

}

var y = f(0);
console.log(y);
```

If I log "num" right before its returned the value is 10.
Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You're missing a `return` at the line `f(num + 1)`

Comment: Because your function doesn't return anything when `num !== 10` is `true`. No `return` statement === returns `undefined`.

Comment: because you don't return the result of `f(num + 1)`

Comment: FWIW, the `if` statement could be condensed to `return if === 10 ? num : f(num + 1);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if num is not 10, you just call f again. The value returned from f is not allocated anywhere. You should return that value.

```
function f(num){
  if(num !== 10){
    return f(num + 1); //you were returning nothing except when num reached 10
  } else {
    return num;
  }

}

var y = f(0);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you elaborate on how the return works? how does f get called again if its just getting returned out of the function? I understand that we need to return to hold the value but I dont get how f gets called again since its being returned out.

Comment: @CW1 f0 calls f1 which calls f2 so on to f10. You want `y` to have the value of f(0). So `y` has the value of whatever f(0) returns. 0 !== 10, so f(0) calls f(1). `y` *should* now store the value of f(1), since f(0) calls f(1). As `y = f(0);` implies, f(0) should return a value so that the value can be assigned to `y`.  So within f(0) let's say this happens: `var t = f(1); return t;`. `t` gets the value of f(1) and returns that. Same thing happens in f(1), where we return the value of f(2). f(10) however does not call any function and return 10. [`var t = f(1); return t;` <=> `return f(1)`]

Comment: @CW1 If it still doesn't make sense, just explain what you don't understand again and I'll try to explain more thoroughly in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather return f(num + 1) inside if block.
 Without which it returns nothing except when "num" reaches 10.

```
 function f(num){
      if(num !== 10){
        return f(num + 1);
      } else {
        return num;
      }
    }
var y = f(0);
console.log(y);
// 10
```